# parser rule not found error while defining grammar

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction, antlr4, lexer

I am new to compiler design as well as ANTLR and trying out some basic stuffs from a book.I came across this problem.Can someone help out. I am expecting the grammar validate any numbers separated by commas in between 2 braces.

Below is my java application to trigger the generated parser but it says at this line `parser.init()` `cannot resolve method init()`. I assume the `init` is the parser rule defined in my grammar.

```
import org.antlr.runtime.ANTLRInputStream;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.*;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.tree.*;

import java.io.IOException;

public class Adamant{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {   
        ANTLRInputStream input = new ANTLRInputStream(System.in);
        testLexer lexer = new testLexer((CharStream) input);
        CommonTokenStream tokens  = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
        testParser parser = new testParser(tokens);
        ParseTree tree = parser.init();
        System.out.println(tree.toStringTree(parser));
    }
}
```

Below is my grammar

```
grammar test;

init: '{' value (',' value)* '}';
value:
    init
    | INT
    ;
INT : [0-9]+ ;
WS :  [\t\n\r] -> skip;
```

Comment: Can't reproduce--works fine. Check `grep 'init()' *.java` and verify that you have `testParser.java:        public final InitContext init() throws RecognitionException {`

Comment: You probably generated a `testParser.java` before you added the `init` rule. Regenerate the java classes again.